# How to extract result content from play.mvc.Result object in play application?

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.0

actually I am doing redirect from one play application to another play application, finally I receive response as Result object.. Below is the action in two applications. I am redirecting from apllication1 to application2. Application 2 will return JSON string, that I need to extract.

How can I retrieve JSON content from Result object?

**Application1:**

```
public static Result redirectTest(){

    Result result =  redirect("http://ipaddress:9000/authenticate");
    /*** here I would like to extract JSON string from result***/
    return result;
}
```

**Application2:**

```
@SecuredAction
public static Result index() {
     Map<String, String> response = new HashMap<String, String>();
     DemoUser user = (DemoUser) ctx().args.get(SecureSocial.USER_KEY);

       for(BasicProfile basicProfile: user.identities){
           response.put("name", basicProfile.firstName().get());
           response.put("emailId", basicProfile.email().get());
           response.put("providerId", basicProfile.providerId());
           response.put("avatarurl", basicProfile.avatarUrl().get());
       }

    return ok(new JSONObject(response).toString());
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think [`play.test.Helpers.contentAsString`](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html#contentAsString(play.mvc.Result)) is what you're looking for.

> ```
> public static java.lang.String contentAsString(Result result)
> ```
>
> Extracts the content as String.

Still available in [Play 2.8.x](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html#contentAsString-play.mvc.Result-).

Answer (score 5):

Use JavaResultExtractor, example:

```
Result result = ...;
byte[] body = JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 0L);
```

Having a byte array, you can extract charset from Content-Type header and create java.lang.String:

```
String header = JavaResultExtractor.getHeaders(result).get("Content-Type");
String charset = "utf-8";
if(header != null && header.contains("; charset=")){
    charset = header.substring(header.indexOf("; charset=") + 10, header.length()).trim();
}
String bodyStr = new String(body, charset);
JsonNode bodyJson = Json.parse(bodyStr);
```

Some of above code was copied from [play.test.Helpers](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/api/java/play/test/Helpers.html)

Comment: JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 0L) gives timeout even if i change it from 0 to 100k

Comment: Wondering why don't use play.test.Helpers.contentAsString(result) ?

Comment: Helpers class have test scope.

Answer (score 2):

This functions works fine for me.. Thanks to Mon Calamari

```
public static JsonNode resultToJsonNode(Result result) {

    byte[] body = JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 0L);

    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    final ObjectReader reader = om.reader();
    JsonNode newNode = null;
    try {
        newNode = reader.readTree(new ByteArrayInputStream(body));
        Logger.info("Result Body in JsonNode:" + newNode.toString());
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return newNode;
}
```

}

Comment: JavaResultExtractor.getBody is giving timeoutexception, even if i increased value from 0 to 100k.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to pass an instance of **akka.stream.Materializer** into **JavaResultExtractor**'s **getbody** method.

Use Google Guice for Injecting at constructor level or declaration level.

```
@Inject
Materializer materializer;
```

and Further you can convert Result into String or any other type as required:

```
    Result result = getResult(); // calling some method returning result
    ByteString body = JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result, 1, materializer);
    String stringBody = body.utf8String(); // get body as String.
    JsonNode jsonNodeBody = play.libs.Json.parse(stringBody); // get body as JsonNode.
```

Comment: After one and a half days of searching, this was the *only* place where I found this solution for "creating" a "Materializer" in Play-2.5-context. This should really have been mentioned in the migration guide from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5...

Answer (score 1):

`redirect` return results with error code 303, which cause the caller (browser) to do another request to the given url.
What you need to do is actually proxying. Application1 should make a request to Application2, and handle the response.
Play have very nice [Web Service API](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.3/JavaWS) which allow doing this easily.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of a controller method you could try:

```
import play.libs.Json;
import play.mvc.Result;
import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonNode;
import org.codehaus.jackson.node.ObjectNode;
...
public static Result redirectTest(){
     ObjectNode body = (ObjectNode) request().body().asJson();
     String providerId = body.get("providerId").asText();
}
```

This SO question may also help: [JSON and Play](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10653350/1956540)

Answer (score -1):

First i write this scala method to convert Enumerator[Array[Byte]] to Future[Array[Byte]]:

```
class EnumeratorHelper {

  def getEnumeratorFuture(body: Enumerator[Array[Byte]]) ={
    Iteratee.flatten(body |>> Iteratee.consume[Array[Byte]]()).run
  }

}
```

Then convert returned Future to Promise and finally get promise value:

```
final F.Promise<Result> finalResultPromise = delegate.call(ctx);
finalResultPromise.onRedeem(result -> {
    F.Promise<byte[]> requestBodyPromise = F.Promise.wrap(new EnumeratorHelper().getEnumeratorFuture(result.toScala().body()));

    requestBodyPromise.onRedeem(bodyByte -> handleBody(new String(bodyByte, "UTF-8")));

});
```