# NullPointerException in async action when converting from Play 2.4 to Play 2.5

Tags: java, playframework, nullpointerexception, playframework-2.5

I'm porting a Play 2.4 project to Play 2.5(.18). I'm running into a spurious `NullPointerException` I cannot find the reason for. This is the stack trace:

```
! @76g5ina3j - Internal server error, for (POST) [/.../tokens] ->

play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException]]
    at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:293)
    at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:220)
    at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:160)
    at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.onError(GlobalSettings.scala:188)
    at play.api.http.GlobalSettingsHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:100)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:273)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:280)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:604)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.exec(CompletableFuture.java:443)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.RunnableGraph.run(Flow.scala:350)
    at akka.stream.scaladsl.Source.runWith(Source.scala:81)
    at akka.stream.javadsl.Source.runWith(Source.scala:528)
    at akka.stream.javadsl.Source.runFold(Source.scala:539)
    at play.http.HttpEntity.consumeData(HttpEntity.java:58)
```

As you see, the stack trace does not feature any reference to code lines in my program, only the framework is mentioned. I already traced the best I could. The Play action is implemented asynchronously using `CompletableFuture` with `supplyAsync` and several `thenApply()` stages. A helper class finally assembles the `Result` by calling

```
return Controller.status(some_resultcode);
```

The ultimate NPE cause starts in `HttpEntity.consumeData()` and ends deep in the Scala parts of Play and in the Akka framework. That `RunnableGraph.run()` method reads

```
def run()(implicit materializer: Materializer): Mat = materializer.materialize(this)
```

While this definitely exceeds my Scala knowledge by several magnitudes, my conclusion is that the only `null` thing here can be that mystique `materializer`, whatever it might be. Where does it come from? What is it good for? How can it be null?

I tried to reproduce the problem with a much, much simpler action:

```
public CompletionStage<Result> version() {
  return CompletableFuture
    .supplyAsync(()->"2")
    .thenApplyAsync(version->ok("Server v"+version));
}
```

Unfortunately, this action runs through without problems, so I do not have a simplified tesimonial of the problem so far.

I'm a bit lost currently. Can anyone explain to me what is going on and how to solve the problem?

Comment: you might have more luck in the play framework google group: https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/play-framework

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, found this one. Things were a bit different after deeper investigation. Actually, the action itself was not the problem. The Controller looked like this:

```
@With(OurLogger.class)
public class OurController extends Controller {

  public CompletionStage<Result> ourAction() {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(()->...);
  }
}
```

The problem was the wrapping `OurLogger`. It featured this:

```
public class OurLogger extends Action.Simple {
  private Result logResult(Result result) {
    System.err.println("Result body: "+
      JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result,1,null).utf8String());
  }
  public CompletionStage<Result> call(Context ctx) {
    return delegate.call(ctx)
      .thenApplyAsync(answer->logResult(answer));
  }
}
```

The problem was the call to `JavaResultExtractor.getBody()`. In Play 2.4, it only gets two parameters. Play 2.5 added a third one - this mysterious `Materializer` which codifies some Akka piping concepts, as far as I understood it. While making the code compileable in Play 2.5, a colleague just added `null` as third parameter - and exactly that `null` was it about which the Akka code deep inside the framework stumbled later upon.

The solution was in the answers section of [How to extract result content from play.mvc.Result object in play application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26301140/how-to-extract-result-content-from-play-mvc-result-object-in-play-application) and lead to the following change of `OurLogger`:

```
public class OurLogger extends Action.Simple {

  @Inject Materializer materializer;

  private Result logResult(Result result) {
    System.err.println("Result body: "+
      JavaResultExtractor.getBody(result,1,materializer).utf8String());
  }

  // call() method unchanged
}
```

I would have found the problem much much faster if (a) the Play migration docs had mentioned this `Materializer` stuff and/or (b) there had only been the slightest hint of this `getBody()` call in the error stack trace in the first place. So it was two days of needle-in-haystack search...